# RadioButton ValidationRule when no option is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, radio-button

I'm trying to figure out how to create a validation rule for a `radiobutton`. What I'm trying to achieve is that the user has to select an option via radiobuttons.

My ViewModel has an `Enum` based property:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Unknown,
    Male,
    Female
}

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Gender = Gender.Unknown;
    }
}

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton Content="Male" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:Gender.Male}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Female" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:Gender.Female}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I have a 'error' style for the checkbox (red border, font color etc)

How should I implement that when the `Gender` is still set to `Unknown` that a ValidationRule is triggered for each of the radiobuttons? (So all show my 'error style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working, not with a `ValidationRule` but with `IDataErrorInfo`.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Gender = Gender.Unknown;
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (name == "Gender" && Gender == Gender.Unknown)
            {
                return "Gender need to be known";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton Content="Male" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:Gender.Male}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Female" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:Gender.Female}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Summary:**

- In code implement `IDataErrorInfo`
- In xaml add `NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True`to `RadioButtons`